# R data.table select rows (i) must use bracket? [in data.table <= 1.9.4]

Tags: r, data.table

Why do these two `data.table` commands result differently?

`DT[num == 1, .N] # returns wrong result`
and
`DT[(num == 1), .N] # returns correct result`

`num` is a numeric column in `data.table` `DT`

EDIT: sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=C            LC_COLLATE=C        
 [5] LC_MONETARY=C        LC_MESSAGES=C        LC_PAPER=C           LC_NAME=C           
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C         LC_TELEPHONE=C       LC_MEASUREMENT=C     LC_IDENTIFICATION=C 

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.4
```

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_0.11.4    chron_2.3-45   plyr_1.8.1     reshape2_1.4.1 stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.1.2

Comment: Getting the same results with `data.table_1.9.5`  It would have been better to provide a reproducible example. `set.seed(24);DT <- data.table(num=sample(1:5, 20, replace=TRUE));DT[num==1,.N]#[1] 3;DT[(num == 1), .N]#[1] 3`

Comment: Most likely an auto indexing (new feature in 1.9.4) bug from 1.9.4. Either do `options(datatable.auto.index=FALSE)` or [update to 1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) until 1.9.6 is pushed to CRAN. It's quite useful to include your `sessionInfo()` (or at least data.table version)

Comment: Thank you akrun and @Arun ! I've edited with session info. Seems like I'm at 1.9.4.

Answer (score 1):

@Arun was right, it seems to be a bug in data.table version 1.9.4 (which is currently latest stable in CRAN).

After github update into 1.9.5, it works correctly:

```
> DT[num == 1, .N]
[1] 2643421
> DT[(num == 1), .N]
[1] 2643421
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=C                LC_COLLATE=C        
 [5] LC_MONETARY=C        LC_MESSAGES=C        LC_PAPER=C           LC_NAME=C           
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C         LC_TELEPHONE=C       LC_MEASUREMENT=C         LC_IDENTIFICATION=C 

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] chron_2.3-45 tools_3.1.2
```